# Numpy sum keepdims error

Tags: python, numpy

Python throws an error when calling numpy sum function on a matrix.

```
probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

The error

```
probs = exp_scores / np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True)
TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'keepdims'
```

Context: Calculate the loss function for a softmax classifier. Numerator is the exponential of the score function for the correct class and denominator is the sum of all the exponentials for all possible classes.

Comment: What's your NumPy version? It sounds really old.

Answer (score 2):

The argument is valid in the latest version of numpy as explained [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html#numpy.sum). Here is the full list of argument for numpy.sum:

> numpy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)

This was added since version 1.7 as you can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/maintenance/1.7.x/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L1422). So, you need to upgrade your numpy installation.

Answer (score 2):

The `keepdims` argument was added in NumPy 1.7. At least the docstring of [`np.sum` (1.6)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.6.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) hasn't listed it as one of the arguments:

```
numpy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None)
```

However the [1.7 docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.7.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) already listed it:

```
numpy.sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)
```

Given that NumPy 1.6 was released in [2012](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy/1.6.2) you probably should update your NumPy package.

However you could also use [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) in case you can't (or don't want to) update NumPy:

```
np.expand_dims(np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1), axis=1)
```